# Can my laravel package update existing config file when installing

Tags: laravel

Is there a way to have my package update an existing config file when installing.

I can add a new config

```
/**
 * Perform post-registration booting of services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->publishes([
        __DIR__.'/path/to/config/new_config.php' => config_path('new_config.php'),
    ]);
}
```

This will update the runtime but I want the package installation to add my config to the main config.

```
/**
 * Register bindings in the container.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
   $this->mergeConfigFrom(
        __DIR__.'/path/to/config/services.php', 'services'
    );
}
```

Comment: I think this is up to user. If you update anything in (source) config file and key-pair is not in "current" (user) config file, source config will be used as well (as complement to "current" config). You sure can instruct users to publish new config file... (or just make new "major" version of package and people will look at changes).

Comment: I've read that you cannot update a config file that your user has already generated. They'd have to make the change.